# Received resources corrupted after migrating to Spring Boot 1.3.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I occured an interesting problem after I updated Spring Boot from version `1.2.6.RELEASE` to version `1.3.0.RELEASE`.

I am currently unable to download any resources correctly. First, I realized there's something wrong with gifs I'm serving: they all had fine content length, but the content was definitely different. I hexdumped both original gif and one downloaded with curl, then diffed them and here is an example:

```
original:
000002f0: 38 FE 20 F5 81 57 00 04 - 23 03 09 12 80 C0 9B 1D |8    W  #       |
00000300: 37 38 00 83 02 DD 81 20 - 01 09 B6 AC 20 C6 0C C7 |78              |

curl'ed:
000002f0: 38 FE 20 F5 3F 57 00 04 - 23 03 09 12 80 C0 9B 1D |8   ?W  #       |
00000300: 37 38 00 3F 02 DD 3F 20 - 01 09 B6 AC 20 C6 0C C7 |78 ?  ?         |
```

As we can see, some bytes (`0x81` and `0x83` in this case, but it also occures with bytes like `0x98`, `0x88`, `0x90`) are read as `0x3F`, which we can observe above as character `?`. I haven't seen anything like it before. I checked headers before and after upgrade, only thing that diffs from previous version is `Accept-Ranges` header. `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` header was added last time I tried this, it doesn't matter if it's there or not.

```
"method": "GET",
"path": "/assets/clock.gif",
"headers": {
    "request": {
        "host": "localhost:8080",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
        "accept-language": "pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "user-agent": some agent,
        "accept": "image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "cookie": some cookies,
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "content-transfer-encoding": "binary"
    },
    "response": {
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=86400",
        "Pragma": "",
        "Expires": "0",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PUT,POST,GET,DELETE",
        "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3600",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
        "X-Application-Context": "IMHS",
        "Last-Modified": "Fri, 04 Dec 2015 14:37:36 GMT",
        "Accept-Ranges": "none",
        "Content-Type": "image/gif;charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Length": "20811",
        "Date": "Fri, 04 Dec 2015 15:38:56 GMT",
        "status": "200"
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot `1.3.0.RELEASE` with Tomcat `8.0.28` (I checked `8.0.21`, Boot `1.2.6.RELEASE` worked like a charm with it, same effect).

Comment: My guess would be that the corruption's happening at build time due to some misconfigured resource filtering

Comment: Hi @AndyWilkinson thank you for your comment and sorry for such a delay. You are correct, shame on me for not figuring it out sooner. I built a jar archive and assets there are already damaged. Maybe changing JDK or Gradle version will fix the problem. Thank you once again kind sir!